# Python enumerate reverse index only

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse, enumerate

I am trying to reverse the index given by `enumerate` whilst retaining the original order of the list being enumerated.

Assume I have the following:

```
>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If I enumerate this I would get the following:

```
>> list(enumerate(range(5)))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)]
```

However I want to reverse the index provided by enumerate so that I get:

```
[(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (0, 4)]
```

So far I have the following code:

```
reversed(list(enumerate(reversed(range(5)))))
```

I was just wondering if there was a neater way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How about using zip instead with a reversed range?

```
>>> zip(range(9, -1, -1), range(10))
[(9, 0), (8, 1), (7, 2), (6, 3), (5, 4), (4, 5), (3, 6), (2, 7), (1, 8), (0, 9)]


>>> def reversedEnumerate(l):
        return zip(range(len(l)-1, -1, -1), l)
>>> reversedEnumerate(range(10))
[(9, 0), (8, 1), (7, 2), (6, 3), (5, 4), (4, 5), (3, 6), (2, 7), (1, 8), (0, 9)]
```

As @julienSpronk suggests, use `izip` to get a generator, also `xrange`:

```
import itertools
>>> import itertools
>>> def reversedEnumerate(l):
...     return itertools.izip(xrange(len(l)-1, -1, -1), l)
...     
>>> reversedEnumerate(range(10))
<itertools.izip object at 0x03749760>
>>> for i in reversedEnumerate(range(10)):
...     print i
...     
(9, 0)
(8, 1)
(7, 2)
(6, 3)
(5, 4)
(4, 5)
(3, 6)
(2, 7)
(1, 8)
(0, 9)
```

Comment: or `itertools.izip` to get a generator

Answer (score 7):

Just take the length of your list and subtract the index from that...

```
L = range(5)

for i, n in L:
    my_i = len(L) -1 - i
    ...
```

Or if you really need a generator:

```
def reverse_enumerate(L):
   # Only works on things that have a len()
   l = len(L)
   for i, n in enumerate(L):
       yield l-i-1, n
```

`enumerate()` can't possibly do this, as it works with generic iterators. For instance, you can pass it infinite iterators, that don't even have a "reverse index".

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this solution is better for you, but at least it's shorter:

```
>>> [(4 - x, x) for x in range(5)]
[(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (0, 4)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your list is not long and you will not run into performance errors, you may use `list(enumerate(range(5)[::-1]))[::-1]`.

Test:

`>>> list(enumerate(range(5)[::-1]))[::-1]
[(0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0)]`

Comment: I provided the most neater way of doing this as I understood. However, this question is kind of taste.

Comment: he wants the indexes to be reversed, not the list

Comment: Oops! Right. fixed.

Comment: This is what I would do as well. I would personally not even care about the last reverse...

Answer (score 4):

Actually I'm using the same logic as @RemcoGerlich did, but I use `list comprehension` directly, which make the code now become 1-liner:

```
def generatelist(x):
    return [(x-1-i,n) for i,n in enumerate(range(x))]
```

Regarding the dilemma of choosing `generator` or `list comprehension`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) is the suggested way:

> Basically, use a generator expression if all you're doing is iterating once. If you want to store and use the generated results, then you're probably better off with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to re-use it several times, you can make your own generator:

```
def reverse_enum(lst):
    for j, item in enumerate(lst):
        yield len(lst)-1-j, item

print list(reverse_enum(range(5)))
# [(4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (0, 4)]
```

or

```
def reverse_enum(lst):
    return ((len(lst)-1-j, item) for j, item in enumerate(lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Python 2

```
import itertools

def reversed_enumerate(seq):
    return itertools.izip(reversed(range(len(seq))), reversed(seq))
```

#### Python 3

Substitute `zip` for `itertools.izip` :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `len(lst)-i` everywhere i is used. or:

```
[(len(range(5)) - x, x) for x in range(5)]
```

Comment: `-(i+1)` or `-1-i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
values = 'abcde'

for i, value in zip(reversed(range(len(values))), values):
    print(i, value)
```

Explanation:

```
values = 'abcde'

values_len = len(values) # 5
indexes = range(values_len) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
reversed_indexes = reversed(indexes) # [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

# combine reversed indexes and values
reversed_enumerator = zip(reversed_indexes, values)

for i, value in reversed_enumerator:
    print(i, value)
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer

Answer (score 1):

We can use enumerate with len:

```
$ cat enumerate.py 


arr = ['stone', 'cold', 'steve', 'austin']
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    print ("enu {} val {}".format(i, val))
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    print ("enu {} val {}".format(len(arr) - i - 1, val))
$  python enumerate.py 
enu 0 val stone
enu 1 val cold
enu 2 val steve
enu 3 val austin
enu 3 val stone
enu 2 val cold
enu 1 val steve
enu 0 val austin
$
```